# How to get a view from content_main.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view, widget

We have in `Android Studio 1.4` new pattern with `conten_main.xml` file.

I need to get a `FrameLayout` View from that file, but by `findViewById()` it's impossibly. Because `ActivityMain.java` has `activity_main.xml` layout, which include
`app_bar_activity_main.xml` layout, which include `content_main.xml` layout.

How can I get a `FrameLayout` view from `content_main.xml` ?

Comment: You can get the frame layout the in the usual way if it was directly present in activity_main.xml. Assign if to the frame layout and access it using findView by id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access your included layout, add an id as follows:

```
<include 
    android:id="+id/id_content_main"
    layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Then access it like this

```
View contentView = findViewById(R.id.id_content_main);
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)contentView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_id);
```